# Native MySQL load balancing

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, load-balancing, openfire

Built Openfire XMPP Server with 2 MySQL database instances ("Master-Master" replicated servers). Trying to achieve database load balancing.
After googling, found native way to achieve load balancing.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-managing-load-balanced-connections.html

During XMPP installation, there is step where I can manually enter database connection string.

[image]

## The question is

if my connection string will look like below

```
jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://[host1][:port],[host2][:port][,[host3][:port]]...[/[database]] »
[?propertyName1=propertyValue1[&propertyName2=propertyValue2]...]
```

will Java's MySQL driver balance connection between multiple servers regardless of which application uses it?

BTW,
There is, database connection statistics on XMPP server. I refresh every time, and it shows me only 1 IP as Database IP. Not randomly changing MySQL servers' ip addresses (from JDBC conection string).